# Well-ordered sets, properties of an element that is not largest in the set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Can anyone please help me in this question:

> $(X,\leq )$ is a well-ordered set. $\forall x\in X$, either $x$ is the largest element of $X$ or there exists $y\in X$ such that
>   (i) $x<y$ and
>   (ii) if $x_0\in X$ such that  $x\leq x_0\leq y$, then either $x = x_0$ or $x_0 = y$.

Will this be sufficient to start the proof:

If $x$ is the largest element then there is nothing to prove.
Suppose $x$ is not the largest element.
$$A=\{ z\in X \mid x<z\}\neq \emptyset$$
How do I proceed?

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Answer (score 2):

You've done all of the necessary creative wok already. All that is left is to apply the definition of "well-founded" and note that this gives you an $y$ with all of the properties you need for concluding (i) and (ii).

Answer (score 2):

You are almost done.

Suppose $x$ is not the largest element of $X$.

Then $Z = \{z \in X : x < z\}$ is nonempty. Since $(X, <)$ is a well-ordering, every nonempty set has a least element. Let $y \in Z$ be least.

Then $x < y$. Now suppose there exists $x_0$ such that $x < x_0 < y$. Then $x_0 \in Z$. But $x_0 < y$ implies that $y$ was not the least element of $Z$. Contradiction.